# WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 is taking time to invoke fault sequence

Tags: wso2-esb

When we are testing fault sequence in our flow, we noticed WSO2 is taking around 10seconds to invoke default fault sequence. Is this predictable behaviour in the product or I am missing something here.

Since the calling of default fault sequence is in the control of wso2 engine, we are not able to test it clearely. but we had out some logger before calling the nd point and logger at the entry of fault sequence and notices the time difference.

So the two logger statements have a gap of more than 10seconds. Would like to know what the wso2 engine doing here.

Comment: anyone has any idea, this WSO2 ESB is not able to handle time outs and throwing out of memory issues....

Comment: It would be helpful to explain this observation if you could explain what is the error in the endpoint that you are experiencing. Is this a situation where endpoint is unavailable? What is the error code you observe?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to provide a better explanation if you can share the error in the endpoint that you observe. Is there an error code? Based on what you have mentioned about the 10 seconds delay, this could be because of the callback processing interval. Please refer to http://blog.maheeka.me/2016/10/mocking-endpoint-behaviours-for.html for more details on this.